# Can't understand the mistake with opening a text file

Tags: python, file, text-files

I'm working on a logging system and have some troubles with trasferring data from the text file to varibale.

```
database = open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\text.txt', 'r')
print(database)
```

When I try to do this, this occurs. What does it mean?

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\Users\user\Desktop\text.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) on reading and writing files for some helpful code snippets. In the example you provided, you have opened the file, but have not `read()` the file

Comment: I'm voting to close this. There is no real problem here, OP just needs to read a tutorial/guide, or the documentation. This isn't what Stack Overflow is for, and I certainly can't see it being useful/relevant in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the data from the file, so you need to use the `read` method.  also, please open the file with `with` so the file will closed automatically, so this is the correct way to do what you want to achieve.

Opening the file with `with`, again, we use this because it will close  the file automatically, and then we are reading the file data with the `read()` method, and finally we are printing the file data.

**Example:**

```
with open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\text.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(data)
    # The file is closed automatically
```

One more thing, you can take the Desktop path by using the **os** module, instead of writing every time **your** Desktop path, it will take **everyone** Desktop path.

We are using the `os.path.join()` to connect two strings together, so this will add a slash (/) between them, and then we are taking the **User Profile** path (`C:\Users\USERNAME`)

So if we are printing the `desktopPath` variable,we are getting this result: `C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop`.

```
import os

# desktop Path
desktopPath = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Desktop')

with open(os.path.join(desktopPath, 'test.txt'), 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the python object containing the file. Instead you likely want to be printing the lines of the file.

try this:
`print(database.readlines())`

Comment: I'm going to use my text file info a lot in the program is I'd really like to transfer it to a variable so I wouldn't have to constantly use "seek" thing.

Comment: Use how? If you just want the contents of the file in a variable, `contents = database.read()`, then you can close the file.

Comment: @Namida I strongly recommend learning more about Python, and programming in general. Stack Overflow is not the place for that.